# How to create pcl::PointIndices from std::vector<int> with `pcl`(Point Cloud Library) in c++?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm using `pcl` in c++, apologizing for not being able to create a `pcl` tag.

I'm realizing a pipe line of point cloud segmentation with `pcl`. I want to know how to create pcl::PointIndices from a extracted indices of type `std::vector<int>`, so I can input it into another filter.

**First filter can generate indices of type std::vector**

```cpp
// Create statistical filtering object
pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<PointXYZ> sor;
CloudXYZPtr sor_filtered (new CloudXYZ);
std::vector<int> sor_inliers;

sor.setInputCloud (input);
sor.setMeanK (10);
sor.setStddevMulThresh (0.5);
sor.filter (sor_inliers);
```

Then, I want input this filtered incides into another filter like:

```cpp
pcl::RadiusOutlierRemoval<PointXYZ> ror;
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr ror_indices (new pcl::PointIndices);
ror_indices->data = sor_inliers;  // #### How to do this line?
std::vector<int> ror_inliers;

//I can set it like
ror.setInputCloud(input);
ror.setIndices(ror_indices);
```

How to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
ror_indices->data = sor_inliers;  // #### How to do this line?
```

Should be:

```
ror_indices->indices = sor_inliers;
```

Comment: Thank you. But, is it a good way to assign like that considering performance?

Comment: If you don't need `sor_inliers` anymore, you can assign from `std::move(sor_inliers)` to move the data which takes almost no time at all.